# Mocking backticks operator in perl 5.8.8

Tags: perl, perl5.8

I am trying to mock the backticks operator in perl version 5.8.8 . From what i have understood is, it is not possible to mock it in perl version 5.8.8. But in perl version 5.9 onward, i can easily mock the backticks operator using

`*CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = \&mock_readpipe`

Is there way to mock backticks operator in perl version 5.8.8. I am able to mock system(), but not backticks.

Comment: `readpipe` couldn't be overriden until Perl v5.8.9. All I can think of is that you wrap the backticks in a subroutine, say `execute`, which does something different if the program is running in a test environment

Comment: Yeah, i can do it. But i was looking for straight-forward solution instead of writing wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can override system() and readpipe(), as they are second-class
>   (overridable) keywords. In Perl 5.8, you can't override qx// or ``,
>   even though they use the same underlying code as readpipe(), simply
>   because they are first-class (non-overridable) keywords. See
>   perl_keywords.pl and opcode.pl in the Perl source code. Why are some
>   keywords not overridable? The main reason is that those keywords are
>   used as part of some further parsing magic, i.e. they don't follow the
>   usual function call style parsing.
>
> The good news is that change [**#29168**](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.changes/2006/10/msg16994.html) to perl made qx// overridable.
>   Hooray! That was released in Perl 5.9.5, and will eventually make it
>   to a maintenance release as Perl 5.10.1. When that happens, setting
>   *CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe will override readpipe(), qx// and ``.

Read complete discussion on perlmonks: [mocking or trapping system calls](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=685699)

Also check out [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm).

Comment: So to conclude it, there is no way at all to mock backticks operator in perl 5.8.8 . Thanks